# How do apply a CSS pseudo element to elements matching multiple classes?

Tags: css

I've had a lot success of applying pseudo elements to single class, but when I only want it to work when a parent class (we'll say `.foo`) also applies, the `content` is not applied before the other class specified (in this case, `'bar`):

```
.foo .bar:before {
  content: "URL: ";
}
```

Is there some way to achieve this?

**Update**

Actual example:

```css
.metajelo-ui_resourceMDSource:before {
  content: " Resource Metadata Source ";
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* FIXME: this is not working for some reason: */
.metajelo-ui_resourceMDSource.metajelo-ui_url:before {
  content: "URL: ";
}
```

The idea is that `:before` should be triggered on any `url`-bearing element that is also a `resourceMDSource`-bearing element (taking the `.metajelo-ui_` prefix into account).

[image]

As we can see, there is a `::before` for the `.metajelo-ui_resourceMDSource`, which corresponds to the first style posted above, however, the highlighted span with the `url` class has no `::before` shown, and there is no `"URL: "` being rendered on the page.

In case this isn't descriptive enough, here is a live demo: https://labordynamicsinstitute.github.io/metajelo-ui/ (click add item for Supplementary Products) - will be happy to fill in more details later.

Comment: Can you show the DOM structure and which element you want the CSS to apply?

Comment: Thanks, I'll update in the next few minutes

Comment: OK, it is now updated, thanks Strelok

Comment: You need a space after `.metajelo-ui_resourceMDSource`

Comment: I see, I think I tried several variations (e.g. space without a "." for the second class) but not that particular variation. That works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you apply the class to the same element...

HTML

```
<div class="foo bar"></div>
```

Then your CSS should look like this...

```
.foo.bar:before { [rules here] }
```

If the class is on any ancestor like this...

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Then your CSS should look like this (space between classes)...

```
.foo .bar:before { [rules here] }
```

Comment: Thanks, but, I don't think this was working my case - see the updated question, which may cover more subtleties.

Comment: Nevermind, that does work - I thought I'd tried that!

Comment: Just pointing out that putting a space between fixes your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the space between `.foo` and `.bar` to select multiple classes (element is `.foo` also is `.bar`).

Here's the code:

```css
.foo.bar:before {
  content: "URL: ";
}
```

```html
<p class="bar alo">bar without foo</p>
<p class="bar foo">bar with foo</p>
```

Comment: pretty sure I tried this as well but it didn't seem to work, i'll look into this in more detail soon.

Comment: Maybe we'll need more context to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question with more details